# delete millions records using partition tables?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

We write daily about 1 million records into a sql server table. 
Records has a insertdate and status fields, among others of course.
I need to delete records from time to time to free space on the volume but leaving the last 4 days records there.
The problem is the deletion takes hours and lots of resources.

I have think about partition tables setting the partition field on the insertdate, but I never used that kind of tables.

How can I achieve the goal using the less cpu/disk resources and having the solution the less drawbacks possible? (I assume any solution has its own drawbacks, but please explain them if you know).

Comment: will delete between an interval help? and split the job into say 10 deletes instead of one big... tried that ?

Comment: Is it really necessary to partition? That is invasive. Just delete in batches and index for deletes.

Comment: Do 1000 records deletions in batch inside a loop while the filter condition is met. That's what I am right now doing. But it takes hours to complete.
This is a task that consumes too much resources to do it too often (even if the set to delete is smaller).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take to speed up the deletion. One is to delete 10000 rows at a time so the transaction log does not grow to an enormous size. Based on some logic you keep deleting top 10000 rows until all the rows fulfill a condition are deleted. This can, depending on your system, speed up the deletes by a factor of 100.

The other approach is to create a partition on the table. You have to create a partition schema and function and if all the rows you are deleting are in one partition, let's say a days worth of sales, then deleting the partition will remove all the rows in a meta operation and it will only take a few seconds to do. Partitioning is not hard but you have to spend some time to set up a rolling window properly. It's more then an hour but less then a week.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
As said in the previous comment your first approach is exactly what I am doing right now. It of couse speeds up the deletion a lot compared to a single delete, but still too long.
About the partition option; what do you mean with "delete the partition". 
Don't you simply write the same delete query and the sql engine takes care to drop/truncate the full affected partition/s?
And what do you mean with "setup a rolling window"?

Comment: You cannot delete a partition - I misspoke - you move it with an alter table switch command and then drop, or truncate, the target table.